# Moxy, JSON and Jersey 2.0 does not deserialize plain String array

Tags: json, jersey, moxy

In my current setup I use Jersey 2.0 with MOXy as discribed in [jersey docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy). I rely completely on the
“Auto-Discoverable Features”, so I do not use any extra configuration or JAXB annotation.

My task is to deserialize an array of strings on the server side. The client is sending the JSON message:

```
["foo","bar"]
```

And on the server side the following method header should deserialize it:

```
@POST
@Path("/stringArray")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response stringArray(List<String> stringList) {
   ...
}
```

**Problem:**
The content of stringList is {null,null}, so the amount of elements is always correct, but the strings are set to null.

The same with a small wrapper class is working. Here the class:

```
public static class Data {
   public List<String> stringList;
}
```

Changing methode signature to stringArray(Data data) and changing the JSON message to:

```
{"stringList": ["foo","bar"]}
```

What is the difference between the two approaches and how can I get the plain string array working?

**Update:**
The described problem is fixed by answer from @Blaise. But the closely related problem of serializing a List of POJOs does still not work. Message:

> [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
>   type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class
>   java.util.ArrayList.]

The only solution I found is again using a small wrapper class containing the List...

Comment: In general it seems to be difficult to serialize/deserialize Collections e.g. List<?> without wrapping them in a class. Can somebody confirm that?

Comment: Problem solved by using org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.5.1.v20130706-f712d02.jar and org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.5.1.v20130706-f712d02.jar instead of the 2.5.0 versions. Thanks to @blaise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is due to a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php):

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/412336

This bug has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build starting **July 5, 2013** from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php