# how to send JS property Array to Jersey JAX-RS JSON based REST web service

Tags: javascript, java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I need to send an array of JS strings to the server side, as part of a field of a JS Object such as:

JSON:

```
{prodName: "abc123", prodImages: ["a1", "a2", "a3"]}
```

I am using Jersey JAX-RS to consume the JSON input.
In my server side code I have:

Web service method signature:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/delete")
public void deleteMethod(ProdListVO prodListDeleteVO) //...
```

JAX-B Object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ProdListVO {   

    private String prodName;
    private String[] prodImages;

// ... getters and setters
```

prodName is correctly set while prodImages is null. Are there any proper JSON formats that Jersey understands as a valid Array or List of String ?

Comment: Have you tried using Collection<> instead of []. (that's what I'm using)

Comment: default JSON provider is Moxxy. Maybe try using Jackson, it should not have  problem with what you are doing. When moved to Jersey 2.X, I tried Moxxy, and I found that List must be wrapped, Map<String,Object > just aren't supported, etc. I replaced it with Jackon and never had any (de) serialization problems.

Comment: see : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson

Comment: @Danielson I tried using the Collection<> and List<> and also String[] none worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after upgrading EclipseLink JAXB Moxy to version 2.6 it solved the problem as based on solution of question:

[Moxy, JSON and Jersey 2.0 does not deserialize plain String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468305/moxy-json-and-jersey-2-0-does-not-deserialize-plain-string-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

> > { "prodName": "abc123", "prodImages": ["a1", "a2", "a3"]}

also include following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

RestClass:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/delete")
public Response callMokuSimple(final JAXBElement<ProdListVO> prodListDeleteVO) {
    ProdListVO prodList =  prodListDeleteVO.getValue();
    // more code
}
```

JAXBClass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)//lets you decide the fields
@XmlRootElement(name="algorithm")
public class Algorithm implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    @XmlElement(name="prodName")//name of field
    private String prodName = null;
    @XmlElement(name="prodImages")//name of other field
    private String [] prodImages = null;

    //getter and setters
}
```